# Multiple Imputation of missing and censored data in R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataset with both missing-at-random (MAR) and censored data. The variables are correlated and I am trying to impute the missing data conditionally so that I can estimate the distribution parameters for a correlated multivariate normal distribution. I would like to use Gibbs MCMC, but am having difficulty implementing the procedure. My dataframe has 5 variables (denoted x1:x5), 1099 samples which contain some combination of MAR, censored and observed values. This is what I have tried so far:

```
# packages
library(msm, tmvtnorm, MCMCpack)

# priors 
theta0<-c(rep(0, 5))
Sigma0<-S0<-diag(5)  
nu0<-4 

# initialize parameters
theta<-c(rep(0, 5))
Tau<-diag(5) 

# initialize output matrix
n_samples <- 1000
mu_MCMC <- matrix(0, nrow = n_samples, ncol = 5)
mu_MCMC[1,] <- theta
cov_MCMC <- matrix(0, nrow = n_samples, ncol = 25)
cov_MCMC[1,] <- c(diag(5))

# detection limits
det_lim <- matrix(c(-1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 1, ncol = 5)

# function to detect NaN (i.e., below detection data)
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x)
    do.call(cbind, lapply(x, is.nan))

for(i in 2:n_samples){
    imputedDF <- data.frame()
    for(r in 1:nrow(originalDF)){
        # variables that are MAR or censored
        mis <- r[, is.na(r) & is.nan(r)]    
        # variables that are observed
        obs <- r[, !is.na(r)]

        # subset mu for missing, observed
        mu1 <- mu[, names(r) %in% names(mis)]
        mu2 <- mu[, names(r) %in% names(obs)]

        # calculate sigmas for MVN partitions of mis, obs
        sigma11 <- sigma[names(r) %in% names(mis), names(r) %in% names(mis)]
        sigma22 <- sigma[names(r) %in% names(obs), names(r) %in% names(obs)]
        sigma12 <- sigma[names(r) %in% names(obs), names(r) %in% names(mis)]
        sigma21 <- t(sigma12)

        # create matrix for detection limits based on missing values
        ## if NaN, use detection limit; if NA use Inf
        dl <- c(ifelse("x1" %in% names(is.nan(r)), det_lim[1, "x1"], Inf), 
                ifelse("x2" %in% names(is.nan(r)), det_lim[1, "x2"], Inf), 
                ifelse("x3" %in% names(is.nan(r)), det_lim[1, "x3"], Inf), 
                ifelse("x4" %in% names(is.nan(r)), det_lim[1, "x4"], Inf), 
                ifelse("x5" %in% names(is.nan(r)), det_lim[1, "x5"], Inf))

        # compute mu, sigma to use for conditional MVN
        ## if all values are missing
        if(length(names(obs) == 0) {
            mu_mis <- mu1
            sigma_mis <- sigma11
        ## otherwise
            } else {
                mu_mis <- mu1 + sigma12 %*% solve(sigma22) * (obs - t(mu2))
                sigma_mis <- sigma11 - sigma12 %*% solve(sigma22) %*% sigma21
        }

        # imputation
        ## if all data are observed, missing is empty
        if(length(obs) == 0) {
            mis_impute <- data.frame()
        ## only need to impute a single value
            } else if(length(names(mis)) == 1) {       
                  mis_impute <- rtnorm(1, mean = mu_mis, sd = sigma_mis, lower = -Inf, upper = dl)
        ## have more than one missing value         
                  } else {
                      mis_impute <- rtmvnorm(1, mean = mu_mis, sigma = sigma_mis, lower = rep(-Inf, length = length(names(mis))), upper = dl)
        }

       # merge observed values with simulated 
       ## if all values observed   
       if(length(names(mis)) == 0) {
           sim_result <- obs
           } else {
                 sim_result <- cbind(mis_impute, obs) 
       }

       imputedDF <- rbind(imputedDF, sim_result)
    }

    # update theta
    v <- solve(solve(Sigma0) + nrow(sim_result)*Tau)
    m <- v %*% (solve(Sigma0) %*% theta0 + Tau %*% apply(sim_result,2,sum))
    mu <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(1,m,v))
    mu_MCMC[i,] <- mu

    # update Sigma
    tmp <- t(sim_result) - mu
    Tau <- rwish(nu0 + nrow(sim_result), solve(S0 + t(tmp) %*% tmp)) 
    sigma <- matrix(c(solve(Tau)), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
    cov_MCMC[i,] <- c(solve(Tau))
}
```

I keep running into errors because the imputation returns NaN and NA values, but I can't figure out what is going wrong because when I test it just using the inner loop to impute the data, it seems to work. Thus, the issue seems to be the parameter updating but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Can you provide your `originalDF` dataframe? e.g. paste the output of `dput(head(originalDF))`?

Comment: Also, this line is missing a closing bracket before the left curly brace (I can't edit it myself, otherwise I would): `if(length(names(obs) == 0) {`

Comment: Unfortunately the original post is about 2 years old - so I doubt we can get you the original df.

Comment: also the user wasnt online the last two years it seems. But you as the bounty.giver could provide a sample data set that comes close to your requirements @JamesThomasDurant? Otherwise you also dont have reproducible code, i guess,..

Comment: This code is unservicable, and I doubt that any of it ever worked. The inner loop starts with `for(r in 1:nrow(originalDF))`, assigning an integer to `r`. Then there's an attempt to create a subset of missings using `mis <- r[, is.na(r) & is.nan(r)] ` – recall that *`r` contains an integer, not a row*. Then there's a series of `ifelse`s with the condition `"x1" %in% names(is.nan(r))` , which contains three problems: 1) once again, `r` is an integer and not a row, 2) `names(is.nan(r))` returns `NULL`, 3) `colnames(is.nan(r))` does work, but it returns all names, so the condition is always TRUE.

Answer (score 9):

### Preamble:

My sense is that part of the problem here is we do not have a good example dataset to work off.

My feeling is we can address this by creating an example dataset to frame the solution discussion. A useful package to this end is the [Wakefield](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wakefield/wakefield.pdf) package that allows for the creation of simulated datasets.

We might, for example, create a dataset of 2000 people, where some of the ages, gender, employment status, education data, and marital status information is missing.

### Imputation

The core question is can we impute the age or gender from other data in the data set?

For example, if we do not know someone's age, can we impute it from their marital status, employment type and or their Education level? At a very simplistic level, we might simply search for entries with NA for age, and look at Marital status. If the marital status is "married", then we impute that our data set is for American's and look up at the average age for marriage and replace with an estimated age for a married person.

We can expand on this and make our estimates more accurate by taking into account more variables. For example, we might look at both Marital Status, Education level and Employment status to further improve our age estimate. If a person is married, with a Ph.D., and retired we push the age upwards. If a person is single, a student we push the age lower. Further to this, we can look at the distribution of the ages in the data set to impute data about missing values.

### Generate an Example Data Set.

```
# packages

requiredPackages <- c("wakefield", "dplyr", "BaylorEdPsych", "mice", "MCMCpack")

ipak <- function(pkg) {
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) {
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  }
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(requiredPackages)

# generate some data for Males with a 8% missing value for
# age

set.seed(10)
f.df <- r_data_frame(n = 1000, age,
                    gender(x = c("M", "F"), prob = c(0, 1), name = "Gender"),
                    employment(x = c("Full Time", "Part Time", "Unemployed", "Retired", "Student"), prob = c(0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), name = "Employment"),
                    education(x = c("No Schooling Completed", "Nursery School to 8th Grade", "9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma",
                                    "Regular High School Diploma", "GED or Alternative Credential", "Some College, Less than 1 Year", "Some College, 1 or More Years, No Degree",
                                    "Associate's Degree", "Bachelor's Degree", "Master's Degree", "Professional School Degree", "Doctorate Degree"),
                                    prob = c(0.013, 0.05, 0.085, 0.246, 0.039, 0.064, 0.15, 0.075, 0.176, 0.072, 0.019, 0.012), name = "Education"),
                    marital(x = c("Married", "Divorced", "Widowed", "Separated", "Never Married"), prob = NULL, name = "Marital")) %>% r_na(cols = 1 - 3, prob = 0.05)

# str(f.df)
summary(f.df)
set.seed(20)

# generate some data for Females with a 5% missing value for
# age

m.df <- r_data_frame(n = 1000, age,
                     gender(x = c("M", "F"), prob = c(1, 0), name = "Gender"),
                     employment(x = c("Full Time", "Part Time", "Unemployed", "Retired", "Student"), prob = c(0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), name = "Employment"),
                     education(x = c("No Schooling Completed", "Nursery School to 8th Grade", "9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma",
                                      "Regular High School Diploma", "GED or Alternative Credential", "Some College, Less than 1 Year", "Some College, 1 or More Years, No Degree",
                                      "Associate's Degree", "Bachelor's Degree", "Master's Degree", "Professional School Degree", "Doctorate Degree"),
                                      prob = c(0.013,0.05, 0.085, 0.246, 0.039, 0.064, 0.15, 0.075, 0.176, 0.072,0.019, 0.012), name = "Education"),
                     marital(x = c("Married", "Divorced", "Widowed", "Separated", "Never Married"), prob = NULL, name = "Marital")) %>% r_na(cols = 1 - 3, prob = 0.03)

summary(m.df)

all.df = rbind.data.frame(m.df, f.df)

summary(all.df)
```

## Data Summary

```
> summary(all.df)
      Age        Gender        Employment                                      Education            Marital   
 Min.   :18.00   M:1000   Full Time :1142   Regular High School Diploma             :459   Married      :394  
 1st Qu.:35.00   F:1000   Part Time : 207   Bachelor's Degree                       :356   Divorced     :378  
 Median :54.00            Unemployed: 193   Some College, 1 or More Years, No Degree:284   Widowed      :411  
 Mean   :53.76            Retired   : 182   9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma     :156   Separated    :379  
 3rd Qu.:72.00            Student   : 196   Associate's Degree                      :145   Never Married:358  
 Max.   :89.00            NA's      :  80   (Other)                                 :520   NA's         : 80  
 NA's   :80                                 NA's                                    : 80                      
>
```

### Is data Missing completely at Random or Not Missing at Random?

```
# Test for MCAR - Missing at Completely at Random...
test_mcar <- LittleMCAR(all.df)
print(test_mcar$amount.missing)
print(test_mcar$p.value)
```

#### Console Output

```
> # Test for MCAR - Missing at Completely at Random...
> test_mcar <- LittleMCAR(all.df)
this could take a while> print(test_mcar$amount.missing)
                  Age Gender Employment Education Marital
Number Missing  80.00      0      80.00     80.00   80.00
Percent Missing  0.04      0       0.04      0.04    0.04
> print(test_mcar$p.value)
[1] 0.02661428
```

### Imputation of Data

Ok, let us first look at the distribution of missing values. We can run [mice::md.pattern()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.5.0/topics/md.pattern) function, to show the distribution of the missing values over the other columns in the dataframe. The `md.pattern()` function output is useful for suggesting which variables might be good candidates to use for imputing the missing values:

```
> md.pattern(all.df)
     Gender Age Employment Education Marital    
1696      1   1          1         1       1   0
73        1   1          1         1       0   1
73        1   1          1         0       1   1
2         1   1          1         0       0   2
71        1   1          0         1       1   1
3         1   1          0         1       0   2
2         1   1          0         0       1   2
71        1   0          1         1       1   1
2         1   0          1         1       0   2
3         1   0          1         0       1   2
4         1   0          0         1       1   2
          0  80         80        80      80 320
```

Ok, from this we can now move to impute the missing values:

```
imp <- mice(all.df, m = 5, maxit = 50, seed = 1234, printFlag = FALSE)
```

- The m=5 parameter specifies that you end up with five plausible imputations for the variable
- The maxit=50 parameter specifies that there will be up to 50 iterations of the algorithm before it converges to a solution and this can be adjusted upward or downward to the desired precision

The mice() function may take a while depending upon the number of iterations we specify. In this case, upon completion we can see some of the imputed values for Age using head() function:

```
head(imp$imp$Age)
     1  2  3  4  5
7   28 49 37 70 89
33  55 54 52 88 24
56  89 83 68 71 61
84  43 43 24 30 31
96  28 64 89 41 50
120 47 34 36 22 77
```

To actually complete the imputation, we have to run the `complete()` function and assign the results to a new dataframe. This version of `complete()` function will collect all imputations in the assigned dataframe via the "long" parameter:

```
all_imputed_df <- complete(imp, "long", include = TRUE)
table(all_imputed_df$.imp, is.na(all_imputed_df$Age))
```

#### Console:

```
> all_imputed_df <- complete(imp, "long", include = TRUE)
> table(all_imputed_df$.imp, is.na(all_imputed_df$Age))

    FALSE TRUE
  0  1920   80
  1  2000    0
  2  2000    0
  3  2000    0
  4  2000    0
  5  2000    0
```

Now we have a dataset of 12000 age values, across 5 age inputted values.

Let's try a regression with imputation #3.

First, extract impute #3

```
impute.3 <- subset(all_imputed_df,.imp=='3')  
summary(impute.3)
```

#### Console:

```
> impute.3 <- subset(all_imputed_df, .imp == "3")
> summary(impute.3)
      .imp        .id              Age        Gender        Employment  
 Min.   :3   Min.   :   1.0   Min.   :18.00   M:1000   Full Time :1192  
 1st Qu.:3   1st Qu.: 500.8   1st Qu.:35.00   F:1000   Part Time : 211  
 Median :3   Median :1000.5   Median :54.00            Unemployed: 202  
 Mean   :3   Mean   :1000.5   Mean   :53.89            Retired   : 191  
 3rd Qu.:3   3rd Qu.:1500.2   3rd Qu.:72.00            Student   : 204  
 Max.   :3   Max.   :2000.0   Max.   :89.00                             

                                    Education            Marital   
 Regular High School Diploma             :478   Married      :416  
 Bachelor's Degree                       :376   Divorced     :390  
 Some College, 1 or More Years, No Degree:295   Widowed      :425  
 9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma     :168   Separated    :393  
 Associate's Degree                      :150   Never Married:376  
 Master's Degree                         :141                      
 (Other)                                 :392
```

Now we can run a linear regression:

```
> lm(Age ~ Education + Gender + Employment + Marital, data = impute.3)

Call:
lm(formula = Age ~ Education + Gender + Employment + Marital, 
    data = impute.3)

Coefficients:
                                      (Intercept)               EducationNursery School to 8th Grade  
                                          51.6733                                             1.4100  
     Education9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma               EducationRegular High School Diploma  
                                           1.3675                                             0.7611  
           EducationGED or Alternative Credential            EducationSome College, Less than 1 Year  
                                           1.0365                                            -2.6069  
EducationSome College, 1 or More Years, No Degree                        EducationAssociate's Degree  
                                           0.3563                                             0.9506  
                       EducationBachelor's Degree                           EducationMaster's Degree  
                                           1.2505                                            -1.6372  
              EducationProfessional School Degree                          EducationDoctorate Degree  
                                           1.1774                                             0.4936  
                                          GenderF                                EmploymentPart Time  
                                          -0.3190                                             1.1316  
                             EmploymentUnemployed                                  EmploymentRetired  
                                           3.1622                                            -0.6855  
                                EmploymentStudent                                    MaritalDivorced  
                                           3.0850                                             0.2934  
                                   MaritalWidowed                                   MaritalSeparated  
                                           2.3162                                             1.6833  
                             MaritalNever Married  
                                           1.6169
```

#### MCMCRegress

```
library(MCMCpack) # b0 = prior mean, B0 = prior precision = 1/variance
fitBayes <- MCMCregress(Age ~ Education + Gender + Employment + Marital, data = impute.3, mcmc = 10000, seed = 1234, b0 = 0, B0 = 0.01, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
summary(fitBayes)
```

#### Console Output

```
> fitBayes <- MCMCregress(Age ~ Education + Gender + Employment + Marital, data = impute.3, mcmc = 10000, seed = 1234, b0 = 0, B0 = 0.01, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
> summary(fitBayes)

Iterations = 1001:11000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 10000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

                                                       Mean      SD Naive SE Time-series SE
(Intercept)                                        48.67377  2.5337 0.025337       0.025337
EducationNursery School to 8th Grade                3.77088  3.0514 0.030514       0.030514
Education9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma        3.81009  2.7794 0.027794       0.027794
EducationRegular High School Diploma                3.24531  2.4933 0.024933       0.025412
EducationGED or Alternative Credential              3.38733  3.2155 0.032155       0.032155
EducationSome College, Less than 1 Year            -0.08419  2.9104 0.029104       0.029577
EducationSome College, 1 or More Years, No Degree   2.82889  2.6092 0.026092       0.026092
EducationAssociate's Degree                         3.32932  2.8410 0.028410       0.028410
EducationBachelor's Degree                          3.72272  2.5228 0.025228       0.025659
EducationMaster's Degree                            0.87738  2.8611 0.028611       0.028611
EducationProfessional School Degree                 3.27542  4.0199 0.040199       0.040199
EducationDoctorate Degree                           2.43794  4.5996 0.045996       0.045996
GenderF                                            -0.11321  0.9327 0.009327       0.009327
EmploymentPart Time                                 1.25556  1.5756 0.015756       0.016170
EmploymentUnemployed                                3.27395  1.6213 0.016213       0.015708
EmploymentRetired                                  -0.52614  1.6394 0.016394       0.016394
EmploymentStudent                                   3.17027  1.6058 0.016058       0.016889
MaritalDivorced                                     0.72379  1.4715 0.014715       0.014715
MaritalWidowed                                      2.73130  1.4394 0.014394       0.014706
MaritalSeparated                                    2.10423  1.4608 0.014608       0.014608
MaritalNever Married                                2.00781  1.4960 0.014960       0.014960
sigma2                                            448.01488 14.0715 0.140715       0.140715

2. Quantiles for each variable:

                                                       2.5%      25%      50%      75%   97.5%
(Intercept)                                        43.75477  46.9556  48.6619  50.3967  53.609
EducationNursery School to 8th Grade               -2.19290   1.7079   3.7701   5.8216   9.718
Education9th Grade to 12th Grade, No Diploma       -1.59323   1.9586   3.8326   5.6676   9.349
EducationRegular High School Diploma               -1.61001   1.5641   3.2474   4.9296   8.155
EducationGED or Alternative Credential             -2.88523   1.2095   3.4173   5.5405   9.691
EducationSome College, Less than 1 Year            -5.75364  -2.0617  -0.1009   1.8986   5.614
EducationSome College, 1 or More Years, No Degree  -2.28754   1.0853   2.8608   4.5718   7.895
EducationAssociate's Degree                        -2.27611   1.4311   3.3285   5.2330   8.978
EducationBachelor's Degree                         -1.21780   2.0258   3.7275   5.4203   8.655
EducationMaster's Degree                           -4.61270  -1.0872   0.8601   2.8484   6.456
EducationProfessional School Degree                -4.63027   0.5900   3.2767   5.9475  11.059
EducationDoctorate Degree                          -6.47767  -0.6371   2.4553   5.4188  11.705
GenderF                                            -1.95673  -0.7298  -0.1067   0.4903   1.727
EmploymentPart Time                                -1.82784   0.1849   1.2597   2.3160   4.354
EmploymentUnemployed                                0.09335   2.1988   3.2674   4.3557   6.433
EmploymentRetired                                  -3.80162  -1.6316  -0.5147   0.5953   2.706
EmploymentStudent                                   0.03387   2.0713   3.1502   4.2227   6.342
MaritalDivorced                                    -2.15073  -0.2732   0.7249   1.7266   3.602
MaritalWidowed                                     -0.13488   1.7817   2.7367   3.6961   5.567
MaritalSeparated                                   -0.76396   1.1177   2.1118   3.0700   5.001
MaritalNever Married                               -0.92230   0.9950   1.9976   3.0248   4.898
sigma2                                            420.98019 438.4621 447.7222 457.2730 476.481
```

Hopefully, the above observations point in the right direction.

#### Citations:

- R Package: [Mice - Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations Reference Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) By: Stef van Buuren
- [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) By Stef van Buuren (***Online Book***)
- [Practical Predictive Analytics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GOJCXNW) by: Ralph Winters
- [Simulation for Data Science with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J3RIG9M) by: Matthias Templ
- [Bayesian Data Analysis, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I60M6H6), 3rd Edition By: Andrew Gelman; John B. Carlin; Hal S. Stern; David B. Dunson; Aki Vehtari; Donald B. Rubin

Comment: Very helpful thank you! What about using imputation on situations when data are censored as well? E.g. i only that      some of my data are below a given limit, or above a given limit, or between two values?

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer! What about using mice or MCMCreg to imput censored data (not missing)?

Comment: James - no worries happy to help. Mice can be used to derive hidden/censored data from other variables, it is a very powerful package. Much of the work in this area derived out of Fritz Scheurens work in developing a solution to a practical problem with missing income data in the March Income Supplement to the Current Population Survey (CPS). Stef van Buuren covers the subject and history of intentionally missing data in his online book "Flexible Imputation of missing data" - see link in the post. See sections 4 Multivariate missing data and  6.3 on Derived variables.

Comment: One thing to be careful of here is that you need to validate your data relationships. I do not have your data set. Think of it this way; does a relationship exist between X, Y, and Z? Mice will allow you to evaluate your data predictors and thus assess your ability to derive missing data correctly. See section 6.3.2 on the subject. Why do I mention? Sometimes you will encounter datasets where you cannot accurately derive missing values by design.  My goal was to try and point you at recommended reading in the context of an example. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JamesThomasDurant Did I address your questions? i.e. You should be able to impute censored data subject to testing that a relationship can be shown to exist with data in your data set.

Comment: Yep i think so. I have situations with environmental contamination data, with some analytes below limits of detection. The analytes, however, are from same pollution source so will be somewhat correlated. I have read Stefs book and seem ti recall that imputation was not directly applicable to censored data, only missing, but will take a look at section you highlighted again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196066/discussion-between-technophobe01-and-james-thomas-durant).